# angular ionic - how to add click event to dynamic created div

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My HTML is creating dynamic divs with `ngFor`

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="scroll" scrollX="true" >

        <div *ngFor="let i of lotes" class="card" id="card_{{i.id_lote}}">
          <div class="title">
            {{ i.nome_lote }}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Then I'm looping an array with ID's and trying to set click listeners on those divs:

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.lotes.forEach(function(lote){

      let card_instance = document.getElementById('card_'+id_lote);
      console.log(card_instance);     // <==================== this works and shows correct element

      card_instance.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        console.log('aaaahhhhh');
      });

    });
  }
```

So I can reach the element but when I click it nothing happens. It looks like the addEventListener don't work...

Am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `click` on the div like this:

```
 <div class="title" (click)="yourFunction(i)">
            {{ i.nome_lote }}
          </div>
```

and in your component just create a function like this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {}

 yourFunction(loteThatWasClicked): void{
    console.log(loteThatWasClicked);
 }
```